# Count per same day DB2

Tags: sql, select, count, db2, where-clause

Can anyone help me with below, any help is much appreciated.

I need check if the account number has came through 3 or more time on the same day only.

This is the Base table:

```
| user_id  | account_no | zip   |      date |
|       1  |        123 | 55555 | 12-DEC-09 | 
|       2  |        123 | 66666 | 12-DEC-09 |
|       3  |        123 | 55555 | 13-DEC-09 |
|       4  |        456 | 77777 | 14-DEC-09 |
|       5  |        456 | 77777 | 14-DEC-09 |
|       6  |        456 | 77777 | 14-DEC-09 |
|       7  |        456 | 77777 | 15-DEC-09 |
|       8  |        789 | 88888 | 15-DEC-09 |
|       9  |        789 | 88888 | 15-DEC-09 |
|       10 |        789 | 88888 | 15-DEC-09 |
|       11 |        789 | 88888 | 16-DEC-09 |
```

I need the below output, I need check if the account number has came through 3 or more time on the same day only.
Output:

```
|       4  |        456 | 77777 | 14-DEC-09 |
|       5  |        456 | 77777 | 14-DEC-09 |
|       6  |        456 | 77777 | 14-DEC-09 |
|       8  |        789 | 88888 | 15-DEC-09 |
|       9  |        789 | 88888 | 15-DEC-09 |
|       10 |        789 | 88888 | 15-DEC-09 |
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions for this:

```
select user_id, account_no, zip, date
from (
    select t.*, count(*) over(partition by account_no, date) cnt
    from mytable t
) t
where cnt >= 3
```

In the subquery, the window function counts how many records exists for the same user on the same day. All that is left to do is to filter on that count in the outer query. To better understand how this works, you can run the subquery first and stare at column `cnt` in the resultset.